# mktime() expects at most 6 parameters, 7 given in

Tags: php, parameters, phpmyadmin, expect, mktime

The Code:

```
$morningstarts = 9;
$eveningends   = 22;
$dst_change = is_dst($month,$day,$year);
$am7=mktime($morningstarts,0,0,$month,$day,$year,is_dst($month,$day,$year,$morningstarts));
$pm7=mktime($eveningends,$eveningends_minutes,0,$month,$day,$year,is_dst($month,$day,$year,$eveningends));
```

That code was working very fine on PHP 5.6 but in PHP 7.1 I'm facing the following error.

> Warning: mktime() expects at most 6 parameters, 7 given in

Please anyone help me out.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php

Comment: Maybe you could include all code to run it? is_dst is not defined in your question.

Comment: @Andreas `is_dst` is irrelevant, the problem is in PHP7 that 7th parameter was removed from `mktime`.

Comment: @Nick  as far as I can see from the manual all versions of PHP should only have six parameters, not seven.

Comment: @Andreas the 7th parameter (`is_dst`) was only *removed* in PHP7. It was deprecated as of PHP5.1

Comment: @Andreas "Note: This parameter has been removed in PHP 7.0.0." It did exist before.

Comment: In case of php 5.6 mktime() work with 7 parameter. In php 7 is_dst parameter has been removed. So try to remove that parameter and run your code successfully.

Comment: @Andreas Please check https://prnt.sc/lrxcoi

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove the 7th parameter in the call to [`mktime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php) and set your timezone with [`date_default_timezone_set`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php), then PHP will deal with daylight savings time for you. e.g.

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Karachi');
$morningstarts = 9;
$eveningends   = 22;
$am7=mktime($morningstarts,0,0,$month,$day,$year);
$pm7=mktime($eveningends,$eveningends_minutes,0,$month,$day,$year);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $timezone = 'America/Chicago';
    $morningstarts = 9;
    $eveningends = 22;
    $am7 = new \DateTime("@" . mktime($morningstarts, 0, 0, $month, $day, $year));
    $pm7 = new \DateTime("@" . mktime($eveningends, $eveningends_minutes, 0, $month, $day, $year));
    $am7->setTimeZone(new \DateTimeZone($timezone));
    $pm7->setTimeZone(new \DateTimeZone($timezone));
```